# "Go to file" feature in various editors

Tags: navigation, text-editor, fuzzy-search, fuzzyfinder, geany

In TextMate there is a feature called "Go to file" that is used for file navigation.  It is a box where you type the name of a file in your project and it will use fuzzy matching to generate a list of candidate files from which you can select.

Other editors have this feature, but they each give it a different name:

Vim fuzzyfinder
Emacs fuzzy-find-in-project
TextMate Go to file (fuzzy)
Eclipse OpenResource (not fuzzy)
Eclipse [GotoFile](http://muermann.org/gotofile/) (fuzzy)
Komodo Go to File (not fuzzy)
Netbeans Go to file (not fuzzy)

Does jEdit, Geany, or Ultraedit have this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across Fuzzy Open for gedit and it works for me.

Give it a try: https://github.com/eggegg/fuzzyopen

Answer (score 1):

Gedit has this feature with the snapopen plugin. You find it on http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

Or you can use the Gmate-Plugins for gedit: https://github.com/gmate/gmate
It is basicly gedit on steroids.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd comment that, in Eclipse, you can get "near-fuzzy" search using wildcard character <kbd>*</kbd>.

For example <kbd>*f*i*l*e</kbd> will find all resources which contain characters f,i,l,e in this order in any place in the name of the resource.

This works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (search for resources) as well as for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (search in open tabs) and others too, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found anything similar for Geany and wrote small prototype it works but has some bugs. github.com/hodzanassredin/geany-fuzzy-goto-file-plugin